# Copy non-contiguous cells and paste in a row retaining number format Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone can help me with this as it's driving me up the wall!

There are 5 non-contiguous cells in a worksheet that I want to copy to the next empty row on another worksheet whilst retaining the number formatting (which varies).  I have this so far but am struggling working out how to retain formatting.  Can anyone please help?  Thanks I anticipation.

```
`With wsCalc

For bRun = 1 To 4
    bData(bRun) = Application.Choose(bRun, .Range("g2"), .Range("b2"), .Range("R2"), .Range("Q14"))
Next bRun
End With

wSResults.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 4).Value = bData
```

`

Comment: Use pastespecial?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .Value, try .Text.  It retains formatting.  See below.

Gary's Student is right, text is read only, it should be used for the input not the output.

```
 bData(bRun) = Application.Choose(bRun, .Range("g2").Text, .Range("b2").Text, .Range("R2").Text, .Range("Q14").Text)
```

I also agree with other answer the entire code could be set up more straight forward.

Comment: It's a bit long-winded, but create two vectors with 5 strings in each. Set the cell address in the first vector, and put the NumberFormat property (which is a string) in the second vector. Then loop over both vectors, using the first to get the value from the source cell, and the second to get its NumberFormat and apply it to the destination cell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion DS_London- I'm not ashamed to say that I have absolutely no idea what any of that means - I'm only a beginner sorry.

Comment: The input could use the .Text property, and then the output would have the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, using your hard-coded cell addresses. You will have to set wsCalc and wsResults to their proper worksheets. Slightly more elegant would be to define a "non-contiguous" range on your wsCalc sheet (select the 1st cell, keep Ctrl pressed and select the next one etc, then type a name in the drop-down box just to the left of the formula bar).

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyWithFormat()
    Dim wsCalc As Worksheet
    Set wsCalc = ActiveSheet 'Or whatever your calc sheet is

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Set rngSource = wsCalc.[G2,B2,R2,Q14]

    Dim wsResults As Worksheet
    Set wsResults = ActiveSheet 'Or whatever your result sheet is

    Dim clDest As Range
    Set clDest = wsResults.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In rngSource.Cells
        clDest.Value = cl.Value
        clDest.NumberFormat = cl.NumberFormat
        Set clDest = clDest.Offset(1)
    Next cl
End Sub
```